# grep+ loop applied to dataframe

Tags: r, string, for-loop

I have dataframe `tab1` - imagine it has 10 rows and 50 columns including the results of the workings below.

I want to search for the string `morse` in every field of `tab1`. I also want to do this for every row.
I do actually get results that work with the code below, but there are 2 things I don't understand which I've put underneath the code

```
tab1$str<-NA
for(i in 1:10) {
   str<-grep("morse", tab1[i,], ignore.case=TRUE)
   tab1$str[i] <- str
}

Error in tab1$str[i] <- str : replacement has length zero

tab1$str
[1] 44 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA          

##the first row, column44 did indeed contain the string, whilst the others did not.
```

Questions:

1. why do I need the first line? `tab1$str <- NA`. Without this, the
   results are wrong with every value of the vector `tab1$str` being
   44, even though they don't contain the string `morse`.
2. why am I getting the error message, even though the results are
   correct?

Generally, I am not a coder and thought this should be simple if I designate the row recursively.

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it's not realy clear what you are looking for, but perhaps you could use the `apply` family to avoid the loop altogether. With this mock data:

```
tab1 <- data.frame(a=sample(c("morse", "other", "foo", "top"), 10, replace = T), b = sample(c("morse", "other", "foo", "top"), 10, replace = T), c = sample(c("morse", "other", "foo", "top"), 10, replace = T))
```

The following function return a list element for every row and shows which column has a "morse" entry.

```
apply(tab1,1, function(x) grep("morse",x))
```

Comment: ...that is exactly what I was looking to do - I don't fully understand it yet,  but it got the results I was looking for. Many thanks, sorry don't yet have enough points to vote up your answer.

Comment: glad to help. googling for 'apply functions r' might help you. you can still accept the most helpful answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. You need `tab1$str <- NA` to initialize the list (a column of dataframe) which you iterate on in `for` loop adding elements for each pass of the `grep()` calculation.
2. Error message is because `grep()` on that certain iteration returns a `NULL` value or `logical(0)` which is an undefined value of no length and so cannot be assigned to an element of vector.

However, your above approach is not optimal because you are assigning to a dataframe a nested list and you do not logically check for the `NULL` value that `grep()` may return.

Consider a vectorized approach using `sapply()` with `ifelse()` which will return a matrix equal to dimension of dataframe recursively checking each column and row. Below `grep()` returns the row index of the *"Morse"* value in column.

```
morse_matrix <- sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grepl("Morse", x), grep("Morse", x), NA))

morse_list <- sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grep("Morse", x), grep("Morse", x), NA))

morse_df <- data.frame(morse_matrix)
```

Comment: `grepl` might be more appropriate than having to worry about `NULL` values.

Comment: thanks - again an awesome answer - haven't reached vectorised code or apply() functions yet in my learning, but I was aware of them. As a result of your answer, I've also learnt more about grep and grepl and how they return answers  -  great help